# Selenium: Unknown HttpClient Factory netty

Tags: java, selenium, processbuilder

While executing selenium code using ProcessBuilder (java), I get the following error message:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:62)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:87)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:80)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:35)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:118)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
> at SeleniumProto.main(SeleniumProto.java:7)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown HttpClient factory netty
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.create(HttpClient.java:57)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault(HttpClient.java:73)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor$DefaultClientFactoryHolder.<clinit>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
>   ... 9 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

The selenium code is below:

```
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumProto {
    public SeleniumProto() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] var0) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\OneDrive\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver var1 = new ChromeDriver();
        var1.get("https://www.twitter.com");
    }
}
```

There aren't many answers on the web on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: This code is working fine for me. Please ensure you have the ChromeDriver of proper version is installed in your system. You may also try to use WebDriverManager of Bonigarcia.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem connected to selenium version or wrong webdriver version. Try with this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.twitter.com");
    }
```

Use the following depedencies:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same or similar issue. I updated the `selenium-java` dependency from 4.5 to the latest 4.18.1, then immediately this error occurred along with slue of other run-time errors. It must be due to incompatibility around `selenium-java` most likely.
When I retracted the version back to 4.5, the errors were gone.